# MySQL left join with sub query produces different results with different sorting

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, left-join

I have 2 tables: **invoices** and **paymentTransactions**. where table paymentTransactions contains entries of payment transactions of invoices - may have multiple entries.

Table: invoices:

```
invoiceId, customerId, amount
```

Table: paymentTransactions:

```
paymentTransactionId, invoiceId, status
```

The requirement is to get the invoices along with the latest payment transaction log.

I tried the below query, but it is returning different results with different sorting.

```
SELECT i.invoiceId,recentTrans.maxTransId,  cts.status as recentStatus  FROM invoices i LEFT JOIN  (SELECT MAX(paymentTransactionId) AS maxTransId, invoiceId FROM paymentTransactions GROUP BY invoiceId) recentTrans      ON recentTrans.invoiceId = i.invoiceId  LEFT JOIN paymentTransactions cts ON cts.paymentTransactionId = recentTrans.maxTransId AND cts.invoiceId = recentTrans.invoiceId WHERE i.invoiceId IN(130623, 3062)  GROUP BY i.invoiceId ORDER BY `invoiceId` desc;
```

[image]

Actually, there is no payment transaction for invoiceId: 130623, but the recentStatus is returning as 1. It is expected to return NULL.

Data:

invoices:

```
invoiceId  customerId amount
3062          1         40
130623        2         60
```

paymentTransactions:

```
paymentTransactionId, invoiceId, status
305                     3062        2
306                     3062        1
```

Appreciating all replies.

Thank you

Comment: Can you add sample data please.

Comment: Added the sample data. Please refresh

Comment: Your query does not produce the result you are seeing and you have a group by which will be invalid if only_full_group_by is set, I cannot reproduce your issue https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: This is what happens when you select non aggregated columns that do not appear in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @P.Salmon
But the only_full_group_by option is disabled

Comment: only_full_group_by s disabled already

Comment: @SanjayKumarNS disabling `only_full_group_by` is the root of your problem.

Comment: @forpas Yes. I have included that selected aggregated column in the group by clause works.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting unexpected results because in the `SELECT` list there are non aggregated columns which are not included in the `GROUP BY` clause.

But you don't need the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT i.invoiceId, cts.paymentTransactionId maxTransId, cts.status as recentStatus  
FROM invoices i 
LEFT JOIN  (
  SELECT MAX(paymentTransactionId) AS maxTransId, invoiceId 
  FROM paymentTransactions 
  GROUP BY invoiceId
) recentTrans ON recentTrans.invoiceId = i.invoiceId  
LEFT JOIN paymentTransactions cts 
ON cts.paymentTransactionId = recentTrans.maxTransId AND cts.invoiceId = i.invoiceId 
WHERE i.invoiceId IN (130623, 3062)  
ORDER BY i.invoiceId ASC;
```

or with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT i.invoiceId, pt.paymentTransactionId maxTransId, pt.status as recentStatus  
FROM invoices i LEFT JOIN paymentTransactions pt 
ON pt.invoiceId = i.invoiceId 
AND pt.paymentTransactionId = (
  SELECT MAX(paymentTransactionId)
  FROM paymentTransactions
  WHERE invoiceId = i.invoiceId  
)
WHERE i.invoiceId IN (130623, 3062)  
ORDER BY i.invoiceId ASC;
```

or if your version of MySql is 8.0+ use a CTE with `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
WITH pt AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY invoiceId ORDER BY paymentTransactionId DESC) rn
  FROM paymentTransactions
)
SELECT i.invoiceId, pt.paymentTransactionId maxTransId, pt.status as recentStatus 
FROM invoices i LEFT JOIN pt
ON pt.invoiceId = i.invoiceId AND pt.rn = 1 
WHERE i.invoiceId IN (130623, 3062)  
ORDER BY i.invoiceId ASC;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=32d57c4919e9de9f90b7305638e0fa51).

```
> invoiceId | maxTransId | recentStatus
> --------: | ---------: | -----------:
>      3062 |        306 |            1
>    130623 |       null |         null
```

Comment: Your second solution plus, I have added the field: paymentTransactionId in the group by clause along with the invoiceId works perfect.

Thank you.